# How do you add Python Imaging Library (PIL) documentation (code completion, etc.) to Netbeans?

Tags: python, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 6.8 as my Python IDE. I can use PIL (1.1.7) in my Python programs, but the code completion features are not working. I just downloaded the Source Kit edition of PIL, but I am unsure if it contains documentation/code completion entries that Netbeans can use.

Does anyone know how to use the PIL documentation with Netbeans (if this is possible?)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did notice this [issue concerning NB 6.7, autocompletion and PIL](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=167989)s... so you may want to update that issue if the info from the previous SO entry doesn't lead to a solution.